# Trouble retaining CustomPrincipal type in HttpContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

I have an MVC app which I'm having trouble ex[posing a custom principal to my views.  It has the following classes that help me manage auth cookies.

```
public class AuthenticationManager
{
    public void SetAuthCookie(UserViewModel user)
    {
        var serializeModel = new CustomPrincipalSerializeModel
        {
            Id = user.UserId,
            Email = user.Email,
            Name = user.Name
        };
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var customPrincipal = customPrincipalMapper.Convert(serializeModel);
        var httpContext = ContextHelper.GetHttpContextBase();
        httpContext.User = customPrincipal;
        var userData = serializer.Serialize(serializeModel);
        var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, serializeModel.Email, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddYears(5), false, userData);
        var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
        var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
        httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
    }
}

public static class ContextHelper
{
    public static HttpContextBase GetHttpContextBase()
    {
        return new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    }
}
```

I also have the following `BaseViewPage` classes which allow me to expose the current user to my views:

```
public abstract class BaseViewPage : WebViewPage
{
    public virtual new CustomPrincipal User
    {
        get { return base.User as CustomPrincipal; }
    }
}

public abstract class BaseViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public virtual new CustomPrincipal User
    {
        get { return base.User as CustomPrincipal; }
    }
}
```

FWIW, this requires `<pages pageBaseType="Giftster.Web.Views.BaseViewPage">` to be in my View's Web.config file.

Immediately, after the `httpContext.User = customPrincipal;` line runs in `AuthenticationManager.SetAuthCookie()`, the type of object which `ContextHelper.GetHttpContextBase().User` returns is a `CustomPrincipal`.  If I refresh the page, however, and put a break point in `BaseViewPage`, `base.User as CustomPrincipal` (and `ContextHelper.GetHttpContextBase().User as CustomPrincipal` for that matter) equals null.  `base.User` is not null, though:  It is of type `GenericPrincipal`, so there is either a casting issue or a problem with storing/retrieving the correct type.

Why is `base.User` in my `BaseViewPage` not of type `CustomPrincipal`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your `CustomPrincipal` from the cookie in each request and add it to the current context. Add the following to the `Global.asax.cs` file

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Get the authentication cookie
  HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
  // If the cookie can't be found, don't issue the ticket
  if (authCookie == null)
  {
    return;
  }
  // Extract the forms authentication cookie
  FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
  // Deserialise user data
  JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  CustomPrincipalSerializeModel data = serializer.Deserialize<CustomPrincipalSerializeModel>(authTicket.UserData);
  // Create principal
  CustomPrincipal principal = new CustomPrincipal(authTicket.Name);
  // Set the properties of CustomPrincipal
  principal.Email = data.Email;
  .... // etc
  // Assign to current context
  HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
}
```

Note also the following line is not required in you `SetAuthCookie()` method

```
httpContext.User = customPrincipal;
```

You might also consider adding the following to a `BaseController` (from which all other controllers derive) so the `CustomPrincipal` properties can be accessed easily in each controller method

```
public new CustomPrincipalSerializeModel User
{
  get { return (CustomPrincipal)HttpContext.User; }
}
```